# How to create "Workflow Service Application" in SharePoint 2016 by PowerShell

Tags: workflow, 2016, central-administration, service-application

In SharePoint 2016 you can **create** "**Workflow Service Application**" and the matching proxy by using Farm Configuration Wizard. As the wizard does more than just creating the service applications you want to create (creates default web application, default service account) it would be nice to create this service application by **PowerShell**.

There is a [New-SPWorkflowServiceApplicationProxy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/new-spworkflowserviceapplicationproxy?view=sharepoint-ps) but no "New-SPWorkflowServiceApplication".

In addition there is no "Workflow Service Application" on the "New" tab in "Manage Service Applications". So I see no way of creating it by gui.

Answer (score 2):

Its not a service app so to speak.

You are connecting to another WFM-Farm. This workflow farm will be granted permissions via oauth and accessed via the proxy only.

Have a look here:
http://www.harbar.net/articles/wfm1.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that was a good information. I could find any of the needed information about Workflow Manager on Technet. I posted the main steps in a seperate answer to help others.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of my confusion is what Heiko Hatzfeld said right. "It is not a service app so to speak".

**To be able to use the service application "Workflow Service Application" and proxy you need to connect it to a Workflow Manager.**

To install a Workflow Manager there are this steps to do:

- Install Microsoft Web Platform Installer 5.0
- Install Workflow Manager
- Configure Workflow Manager
- Install Workflow Manager Client on SharePoint Server
- Register "Workflow Service Application Proxy" in SharePoint

There is a pretty good article "[SharePoint 2016: Step By Step Installation of Workflow Manager](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34407.sharepoint-2016-step-by-step-installation-of-workflow-manager.aspx)" on Technet which describes all steps pretty good.